# How to find full package import from CallExpr

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

The following method extracts all public method calls from the AST of a file. I need to find out the full package from the CallExpr, for example: ast.Inspect() is imported from "go/ast". I want to match the list of pkgsInclude strings with the imported package name:

```
func functionCalls(path string, node *ast.File, pkgsInclude []string) int {
    fCalls := 0
    ast.Inspect(node, func(n ast.Node) bool {
        switch fCall := n.(type) {
        case *ast.CallExpr:
            if fun, ok := fCall.Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr); ok {
                if fun.Sel.IsExported() {
                    fCalls += 1
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    })
    return fCalls
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the "ast".File.Imports along with "go/importer".Default() ?

Comment: You can do this using the AST alone if you are looking for calls like `pkgname.FuncName()`.  You will need to resolve the identifiers (using NewPackage?).  From there, you can dig into SelectorExpr.X to find the package.  Otherwise, use go/types.

Answer (score 9):

To get fully qualified names, the code has to be type checked with the go/types package.

[The go/types article by Alan Donovan](https://github.com/golang/example/tree/master/gotypes#introduction) goes into great detail on how to use the type checker properly, but here is the gist of it. I left a few type assertions in the Visit method for brevity. In production code you shouldn't assume specific node types.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
    "log"
)

// code to parse. It includes two variants of calling a package function.
var code = `package main

import (
    foo "io/ioutil"
    . "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    foo.ReadFile("")
    ReadFile("")
}
`

func main() {
    fset := &token.FileSet{}
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", code, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    // info.Uses allows to lookup import paths for identifiers.
    info := &types.Info{
        Uses: make(map[*ast.Ident]types.Object),
    }

    // Type check the parsed code using the default importer.
    // Use golang.org/x/tools/go/loader to check a program
    // consisting of multiple packages.
    conf := types.Config{Importer: importer.Default()}

    pkg, err := conf.Check("main", fset, []*ast.File{f}, info)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Do something with ast, info, and possibly pkg
    var _ = pkg

    ast.Walk(v{info}, f)
}

type v struct {
    info *types.Info
}

func (v v) Visit(node ast.Node) (w ast.Visitor) {
    switch node := node.(type) {
    case *ast.CallExpr:
        // Get some kind of *ast.Ident for the CallExpr that represents the
        // package. Then we can look it up in v.info. Where exactly it sits in
        // the ast depends on the form of the function call.

        switch node := node.Fun.(type) {
        case *ast.SelectorExpr: // foo.ReadFile
            pkgID := node.X.(*ast.Ident)
            fmt.Println(v.info.Uses[pkgID].(*types.PkgName).Imported().Path())

        case *ast.Ident:        // ReadFile
            pkgID := node
            fmt.Println(v.info.Uses[pkgID].Pkg().Path())
        }
    }

    return v
}

// Output:
// io/ioutil
// io/ioutil
```

Comment: Note that, as of go 1.12 with modules, you'll want to use golang.org/x/tools/go/packages instead of golang.org/x/tools/go/loader